# What is <user>@<server> notation called?

Tags: database, unix

When connecting to a database or server, what is that particular kind of notation called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Account name syntax is 'user_name'@'host_name'.

It’s called account name syntax, at least in MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-names.html).